# How to you external functions and variables in MatLab App Designer

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I am trying to create a Matlab GUI using the app designer for a project. I got the program working without the gui but need to make one. Is it possible to call functions and specific variables within those functions that are in their own separate .m files into the app's callback code? if so how would I be able to do this?

I tried directly referencing the functions which work, however, when I trying reference the specific variable within the function such as proj8(x_der); it say the variable is unrecognized.

Answer (score 0):

There is several possibilities can be done like using global variable and such. But, global variable not recomended and may cause problem later on.

More proper way is setting up variable within the function as a output variable if I correctly understand your question.

```
[ref_variable] = proj8(input_var)
```

Just in case you need to plot a plot using certain variable within function, directly use plot command from within function will also work.

Comment: to be exact these functions aren't within the app designer code. they are separate function files in Matlab. the app designer is in the same file path (same folder). im trying use the functions and variables I already designed, and just make the gui useable with them.